# Why am I getting a 404 error in SignalR Backplane with SQL Server in .Net Core?

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

Anyone successfully implemented SignalR Backplane with SQL Server in .Net Core application ?

We are using IntelliTect.AspNetCore.SignalR.SqlServer as mentioned in this article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The Sql tables are created successfully, but it tables are populated with the payload data. So we are getting 404 error in the multi server environment.

We have tried this middleware. It is creating tables but not inserting any records
services
.AddSignalR()
.AddSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));

Comment: Please share more error details about the 404 error, like url or error message, we need to know when the issues occured.